# Why is my animation so slow?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, manipulate, animation

I have an animated plot of the kind

```
Manipulate[
 plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[randomsample[s], {s, 0, t}, 
                          PlotStyle -> Red,
                          Evaluated -> True];
 plot2 = ListPointPlot3D[coord3D[t]];
 Show[plot1,
      plot2,
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
      ImageSize -> Large,
      AspectRatio -> 1,
      ViewPoint -> viewpoint, 
      PlotLabel -> Style["time " <> ToString[NumberForm[t, {4, 2}]] <> " whatevers", 20]]
 ,
 {t, 0, 15, ControlType -> Animator},
 {{viewpoint, {Infinity, 0, 0}},
  {{3, 3, 1} -> "3D",
   {Infinity, 0, 0} -> "Front",
   {0, 0, Infinity} -> "Top",
   {0, Infinity, 0} -> "Side"}}]
```

making use of source data such as

```
coord3D0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {450, 3}];
ρ0 = Norm /@ coord3D0;
θ0 = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 450];
vθ = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 450];
θ[t_] = vθ/ρ0 t + θ0;
kvectors = Normalize /@ MapThread[
   Cross,
   {Evaluate[Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {450, 3}]], coord3D0}];
coord3D[t_] = Simplify@Chop[
   coord3D0*Cos[θ[t]] + MapThread[Cross, {kvectors, coord3D0}] Sin[θ[t]] + MapThread[#1 (#1.#2) &, {kvectors, coord3D0}] (1 - Cos[θ[t]])];
randomsample[t_] = RandomSample[coord3D[t], 30];
```

The point is, it works, but it runs *reeeeeeally* slow on my laptop. Now my question is threefold:

1. How can I make it run faster?
2. Did I do something specifically wrong or have I somehow run into Mathematica's limitations as regards 3D animated plotting? Could it be that this is not the way I'm supposed to be combining plots inside a `Manipulate`?
3. What *are* Mathematica's "practical" limitations in this respect? I.e., how can I make a reasonable guess as whether an animated plot will be able to run smoothly? How much is too much?

**EDIT:** The problem seems linked to the `ParametricPlot3D` code, since the `ListPointPlot3D` runs smoothly by itself, while the parametric plot doesn't. Heretofore I have tried using a `RegionFunction` specification and an `Exclusion` specification in place of its dynamic upper limit, both unsuccessfully.

Comment: It is not really lethally slow on my machine - what kind of hardware do you use? Can you supply some useful `Timing`s?

Comment: I use MMA 8.0.1.0 on an Intel i3 machine running Windows 7, with 4GB DDR3 and a NVIDIA GeForce 310M. I am not sure what kinds of `Timing`s would be useful, since the problem is not that it takes time to start, but rather that the animation looks very much "stop motion"-like. However, I have noticed that it strongly depends on the number of "particles" whose trajectory I track: this slowing becomes negligible at a `RandomSample` of about 10.

Comment: `Simplify` is probably not necessary and you may try getting rid of that and see if it helps (no noticeable difference for me).

Comment: The `Simplify` is actually one my futile attempts at making this thing run faster. I have noticed that the problem is probably in the `ParametricPlot3D`, as it is present even if I do not combine the two plots, only using the former. This might actually be meaningful.

Comment: Try to identify whatever slows this down (e.g. by elimination of plot components), then we can try to speed that up.

Comment: Does using the option `PerformanceGoal-> "Speed" ` as in `ParametricPlot3D[randomsample[s], {s, 0, t}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Evaluated -> True, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]` help?

Comment: I think Ives found the handle to use, you could e.g. use `PerformanceGoal -> $PerformanceGoal` which will use a faster version when animating and a more expensive variant when the animation is stopped. The two options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursions` would give somewhat more control about what `"Speed"` or `"Performance"` would mean, e.g.: `PlotPoints -> ($PerformanceGoal /. {"Speed" -> 15, _ -> 
     Automatic}), MaxRecursion -> ($PerformanceGoal /. {"Speed" -> 
     3, _ -> Automatic})`. @Yves: would you want to write an answer?

Comment: @AlbertRetey please be my guest to answer, busy at the moment...

Comment: @YvesKlett Not much, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To speed up the animation - pre-compute and then animate:

```
coord3D0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {450, 3}];
ρ0 = Norm /@ coord3D0;
θ0 = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 450];
vθ = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 450];
θ[t_] = vθ/ρ0 t + θ0;
kvectors = Normalize /@ MapThread[
   Cross,
   {Evaluate[Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {450, 3}]], coord3D0}];
coord3D[t_] = Simplify@Chop[
   coord3D0*Cos[θ[t]] + MapThread[Cross, {kvectors, coord3D0}] Sin[θ[t]] + 
   MapThread[#1 (#1.#2) &, {kvectors, coord3D0}] (1 - Cos[θ[t]])];
randomsample[t_] = RandomSample[coord3D[t], 30];


gl = Table[plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[randomsample[s], {s, 0, t}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     Evaluated -> True];plot2 = ListPointPlot3D[coord3D[t]];
   Show[plot1, plot2, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> 
  {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> 
  Style["time " <> ToString[NumberForm[t, {4, 2}]] <> " whatevers", 20]], {t, .1, 15, .3}];


Manipulate[Show[gl[[n]], ViewPoint -> Dynamic@viewpoint], {n, 1, Length[gl], 1, 
  Animator, AnimationRate -> 10, AnimationRunning -> False}, 
 {{viewpoint, {Infinity, 0, 0}}, {{3, 3, 1} -> "3D", 
 {Infinity, 0, 0} -> "Front", {0, 0, Infinity} -> "Top", {0, Infinity, 0} -> "Side"}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are after a "final" high quality answer, I think Vitaly's suggestion to pre-compute is the best you can do. If you rather do some exploration and don't want to wait for the lengthy precomputing to finish before seeing the results you could try to speed up the `ParametricPlot3D`. The most simple version is to set `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` as Yves has suggested. You can get some finer control about what `"Speed"` actually does by using the options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursions`, as e.g. here:

```
Manipulate[
 plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[randomsample[s], {s, 0, t + $MachineEpsilon},
       PlotStyle -> Red, Evaluated -> True,
       PlotPoints -> ($PerformanceGoal /. {"Speed" -> 15, _ -> Automatic}), 
   MaxRecursion -> ($PerformanceGoal /. {"Speed" -> 3, _ -> Automatic})
   ];
 Show[plot1,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
  ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1, ViewPoint -> viewpoint, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["time " <> ToString[NumberForm[t, {4, 2}]] <> " whatevers", 
    20]
  ],
 {t, 0, 15, ControlType -> Animator},
 {{viewpoint, {Infinity, 0, 0}}, {
   {3, 3, 1} -> "3D",
   {Infinity, 0, 0} -> "Front",
   {0, 0, Infinity} -> "Top",
   {0, Infinity, 0} -> "Side"}
  }
 ]
```

Note that the global `$PerformanceGoal` is used to create a fast preview while the animation is running (or the controls are changing) but to show a precise version (using the default values) when the animation is stopped. You'll notice quite some differences in the two versions, so you might want to fine tune the values for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` so that your preview is a decent compromise between speed and quality for your application.